# HTTP Status 404. description The requested resource is not available

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

I've got a page here. When I click the submit button, I get the 404 page saying:

```
HTTP Status 404 - /Email/EmailGet


type Status report

message /Email/EmailGet

description The requested resource is not available.


Apache Tomcat/7.0.47
```

Code:

```
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="EmailGet" method="GET">
        Email: <input type="text" name="email"> <br> Password: <input
            type="password" name="password"> <br> <input
            type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's the EmailGet code:

```
package email;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class Controller
 */
@WebServlet("/EmailGet")
public class EmailGet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public EmailGet() {
        super();
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // Gets the entered email and password

        String username = request.getParameter("email");
        String password = request.getParameter("password");

        //Creates the session and sets the session attributes

        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        session.setAttribute("username", username);
        session.setAttribute("password", password);

        RequestDispatcher dispatcher;

        //Calls the setCredentials method to check if entered credentials are valid

        boolean result = SendSMTPMail.setCredentials(username, password);

        //if valid, forwards to send page
        if (result == true) {
            dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("send.jsp");
            dispatcher.forward(request, response);      
        }

        //if not valid, forwards to index page with error message displayed
        else {
            dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("indexerror.jsp");
            dispatcher.forward(request, response);      
        }

    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }


}
```

Any ideas? It used to forward the page fine, but seems not to be working now.

Each jsp page runs fine individually, it's just the forwarding that isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

It seems. . . that the requested page does not exist. I don't know the names of you files, so i can only guess that you have a typo somewhere, try to check your url bar and check if this is really the url you wanted.

Comment: Would http://localhost:8080/Email/EmailGet?email=&password= be the same page as http://localhost:8080/Email/send.jsp/?

Comment: @John No. Try to change the `<form action="EmailGet" method="GET">` to `<form action="send.jsp" method="GET">`

Comment: I need to run the doGet in the EmailGet.java class after pressing submit though. The EmailGet.java code (posted above) should forward my page onto send.jsp, and I can't see why it's not

Comment: try `@WebServlet(value="/EmailGet", name="[script name]")`

Comment: @John forgot to mention you -_-

Comment: Bleh. I figured everything out. I'm back on a different computer, and it's working again. No idea why it wasn't working before. Thanks for your help anyway :)